# How to ask player if they would like to retry when they die and if they say yes then make the game restart

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to add a function that asks the player If they want to restart and If they type yes, then the game should restart.

I have looked it up but found nothing that helps me

```
elif response_turn3 == "right":
                  print("You carry on down the path, whistling a merry tune.")
                  time.sleep(4)
                  print("Suddenly, a flash flood sweeps you away, freezing you to death in the cold, icy water.GAME OVER :(")
                  print("Try again?")
```

Then it would be something like

```
   (if yes then restart)
```

How would this work in code?

In order to do this, I would need to define a function like `game_start()`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Input validation, even minimal, is a useful tool.

```
valid_answer = False
while not valid_answer:
  answer = input("Try again? (y/n)")
  if answer == 'y' or answer == 'n':
    valid_answer = True
    if answer == 'y':
      restart_game()
    else:
      quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the input function in python.

```
try_again = input("Try again?")
if (try_again == True):
    game_start()
```

And then depending on the input, you can call the function that starts the game again.

Comment: It just returns with game_start not defined

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

A simple way to achieve what you require would be to use a `while` loop. At the end of each iteration (game) you should ask the user if they would like to continue, and if not break out of the loop.

I would suggest you take your existing code and re-cast it as a `play_game` function that returns when the game is over. This will allow you to terminate the game with a `return` statement at any point in your logic, which will probably make your logic simpler too.

Supposing you had done that, you could then write a loop like

```
while True:
    play_game()
    answer = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    if not ('y' in answer.lower()):
        break
```

The dialogue with the user could be more sophisticated, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: how would i recast the game with a play_game function?

Comment: That's difficult to say without seeing your logic. If you can isolate a section that from beginning to end takes the player through a complete game, indent that section by four spaces and precede it with a non-indented line reading `def play_game():` - but this is a very simplistic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't possible to restart a script only using python commands (You can use [`os.System()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) but it's rather complicated). But you can enclose the script in a function `game()` then call it when the user says yes.

```
elif response_turn3 == "right":
              print("You carry on down the path, whistling a merry tune.")
              time.sleep(4)
              print("Suddenly, a flash flood sweeps you away, freezing you to death in the cold, icy water. GAME OVER :(")
              response=input("Try again?")
              if(response=="yes"):
                            game()
```